# Google Edge TPU dev-board cannot be reconized by macOS BigSur

Tags: google-coral, google-developer-tools, edge-tpu

I have trouble getting started with the edge Tpu dev-board.
Following the [instruction](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/get-started/#flash-the-board), I have complete the first three steps.

However, according to [step 4](https://coral.ai/docs/dev-board/mdt/#mdt-on-macos), I have to create an MDT via a local network.

Everytime I ran  `ls /dev/cu.usbmodem*` . The shell appear:

> zsh: no matches found: /dev/cu.usbmodem*

The result of the command `mdt shell` is still waiting for a device.

And the solution `screen /dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART 115200` also show no file exist to me.

Also, is it normal for the fan to stop after a while when the board is powered on?

Comment: Open issue waiting to be solved for several months: https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/296#issue-786417660

Comment: Thanks! Have you solved that issue?